# websphere MQ Message get error?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

Recently I attended an interview, he asked this question
I am putting messages in Q. Manager, but client unable to get that messages, what is the problem can you explain it?
(All permission are ok, and put and get are enable state).

Answer (score 1):

There are a 101 possible reasons. That is why MQ provides an MQRC back to the application, and further information in the AMQERR01.LOG. Without either of those you cannot even begin to guess. (P.S. I suspect that would have been a suitable reply in an interview!!)

But, since you ask for us to guess, here's a few more different from those Valerie suggested.

- Perhaps the client channel max message length is shorter than the messages on the queue.
- The codepage between client and queue manager may be such that data cannot be converted.
- Client application get buffer isn't big enough
- Hasn't specified accept truncated and the message was bigger than the buffer
- AMS is in use and he's not the intended recipient (different from permissions)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, would need to check error code received by client.  Could be programming situation where client is getting based on a specific message or correl ID that does not exist.  Could be that channel auth is blocking client.  Also, it could be that the putting application did not commit the messages so they are not really available for the get.